# How to use the ROUNDDOWN action along with an IF statement in a calculated column

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a calculated column that is using a conditional IF statement to do a calculation.I am using a variation of this in 3 different Calc columns. The problem i have is that my amount are rounding up and I end up with an extra penny which in accounting is a no no. How do I incorporate a round down into this formula.

```
=IF([DTF/DWI/Admin/Jud]="DTF",([Sale Price]-[Title Transfer]-Towing-[Other Expenses])*0.7, 
IF([DTF/DWI/Admin/Jud]="DWI",([Sale Price]-[Title Transfer]-Towing-[Other Expenses])*0.7,
IF([DTF/DWI/Admin/Jud]="Jud",([Sale Price]-[Title Transfer]-Towing-[Other Expenses])*0.7,
IF([DTF/DWI/Admin/Jud]="Admin","0"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint, you can use [ROUNDDOWN(number,num_digits)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rounddown-function-2ecb3677-7a76-4634-830f-512a92c1d62c) function to rounds a number down, toward zero.

In your case, the final formula should be

```
=ROUNDDOWN(IF([DTF/DWI/Admin/Jud]="DTF",([Sale Price]-[Title Transfer]-Towing-[Other Expenses])*0.7, 
IF([DTF/DWI/Admin/Jud]="DWI",([Sale Price]-[Title Transfer]-Towing-[Other Expenses])*0.7,
IF([DTF/DWI/Admin/Jud]="Jud",([Sale Price]-[Title Transfer]-Towing-[Other Expenses])*0.7,
IF([DTF/DWI/Admin/Jud]="Admin","0")),0)
```

So if the result, for example, is **3.3**, the result of the `ROUNDDOWN(3.3,0)` will be **3**

Comment: I had to add 2 more ) at the end of the Formula before the ,0) otherwise I was getting a syntax error otherwise this is exactly what I needed Thanks